# PHP 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint

Tags: php, mysql

What it should do: delete a customer from the customer table.

SQL for borrower and customer tables:

```
create table customer
   (customer_name       varchar(15)     not null,
    customer_street     varchar(12)     not null,
    customer_city       varchar(15)     not null,
    primary key(customer_name))ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table borrower
   (customer_name       varchar(15)     not null,
    loan_number         varchar(15)     not null,
    primary key(customer_name, loan_number),
    foreign key(customer_name) references customer(customer_name),
    foreign key(loan_number) references loan(loan_number)
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I know I need to drop tables with foreign keys first due to referential integrity constraints. How can I drop the table with the foreign key first?
Error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databaseName`.`borrower`, CONSTRAINT `borrower_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_name`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_name`))' in /banking_update.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 /banking_update.php(18): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /banking_update.php on line 18
```

PHP Code so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style = "width:30%; float:left">
</div>

<?php 
include_once 'banking_db.php';
# form data
$customer_name=isset($_POST['customer_name']) ? $_POST['customer_name'] : '';
$customer_street=isset($_POST['customer_street']) ? $_POST['customer_street'] : '';
$customer_city=isset($_POST['customer_city']) ? $_POST['customer_city'] : '';
$query = "update customer set customer_name = :customer_name, customer_street = :customer_street, customer_city = :customer_city;";
$data = array( 'customer_name' => $customer_name, 'customer_street' => $customer_street, 'customer_city' => $customer_city);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
if($stmt -> execute($data))
{
   $rows_affected = $stmt->rowCount();
   echo "<h2>".$rows_affected." row updated sucessfully!</h2>";
   include 'banking_display.php';
   display("SELECT * FROM customer;");
}
else
{
  echo "update failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You _probably_ want to [CASCADE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/74627/difference-between-on-delete-cascade-on-update-cascade-in-mysql) when you UPDATE or DELETE data on those foreign keys... assuming you want to delete `borrower` records when you delete customers.

Comment: @CD001 I added CASCADE and got the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like it was already said in the coments you need to add `ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`to the foreign key.

**But** your query would update **all** the customers with the same information, so add a `WHERE clause to your query

> ```
> create table customer
>    (customer_name       varchar(15)     not null,
>     customer_street     varchar(12)     not null,
>     customer_city       varchar(15)     not null,
>     primary key(customer_name))ENGINE=InnoDB;
>
> create table borrower
>    (customer_name       varchar(15)     not null,
>     loan_number         varchar(15)     not null,
>     primary key(customer_name, loan_number),
>     foreign key(customer_name) references customer(customer_name)
>         ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)ENGINE=InnoDB;
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO customer VALUES ('TEST','teststreet','Testcity')
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO borrower VALUES ('TEST','loan1')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE customer SET customer_name = 'test1', customer_street = 'teststreet1' WHERE customer_name = 'TEST'
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM customer
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_name | customer_street | customer_city
> :------------ | :-------------- | :------------
> test1         | teststreet1     | Testcity
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b5336331f16226ec6c451e99fd2bcd5)*